# What blog reading websites are Kindle friendly?

Tags: rss, blog, kindle, rss-reader

My favorite blog reading applications are ajax heavy sites that are likely to crash the "experimental" browser on the Kindle.

What web site can I use to aggregate my favorite RSS feeds and get an acceptable layout and minimize browser crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Kindlefeeder](http://kindlefeeder.com/) ?

> Kindlefeeder is a service for Amazon Kindle owners that lets you aggregate your favorite feeds and have them delivered to your Kindle in a convenient, easy-to-navigate format. Kindlefeeder also lets you save individual webpages and have them delivered to your Kindle along with your feeds.

Comment: Works great, I'm reading the stackoverflow blog on it right now!